# How to send net-export from chrome on ipad?

Tags: google-chrome, ipad, google-chrome-devtools

I'm, using chrome://net-export to get network information from chrome on iPad (2021 M1 iPad Pro). I am able to log information. It logs data to /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/##some guid##/tmp/net-export/chrome-net-export-log.json.

This file is in a location I can't easily access on my ipad. There is an option on the page to "Email Log". However, when I click the "Email Log" button, I get the error below

> NO EMAIL ACCOUNTS
> To send net-export data, please configure your email account in the settings app.

I have 3 different google accounts logged in with chrome and turned on sync for "Addresses and More", but I'm still receiving this message.

How do I export this data (or access the log) on my ipad?

Answer (score 0):

The error:
"NO EMAIL ACCOUNTS" indicates that the Chrome app on your iPad is not detecting any email accounts, thus cannot send the log file. The Chrome app looks for emails accounts configured within the iOS, not within the Chrome app.

Comment: I do have my gmail configured in iOS, which is accessible via both the mail app and gmail app. Not sure if I’m missing something?